# PHP Array & XML Can't get all content

Tags: php, arrays, xml, for-loop, simplexml

I'm tring to get all content from this xml: https://api.eveonline.com/eve/SkillTree.xml.aspx

To save it on a MySQL DB.

But there are some data missing...

Could any1 that understand PHP, Array() and XML help me, please?

This is my code to get the content:

```
<?php

    $filename = 'https://api.eveonline.com/eve/SkillTree.xml.aspx';
    $xmlbalance = simplexml_load_file($filename);
    $skills = array();

    for ($x=0;$x<sizeOf($xmlbalance->result->rowset->row);$x++) {
         $groupName = $xmlbalance->result->rowset->row[$x]->attributes()->groupName;
         $groupID = $xmlbalance->result->rowset->row[$x]->attributes()->groupID;
         for ($y=0;$y<sizeOf($xmlbalance->result->rowset->row[$x]->rowset->row);$y++) {
             $skills[$x]["skillID"] = "".$xmlbalance->result->rowset->row[$x]->rowset->row[$y]->attributes()->typeID;
             $skills[$x]["skillName"] = "".$xmlbalance->result->rowset->row[$x]->rowset->row[$y]->attributes()->typeName;            
             $skills[$x]["skillDesc"] = "".$xmlbalance->result->rowset->row[$x]->rowset->row[$y]->description;
             $skills[$x]["skillRank"] = "".$xmlbalance->result->rowset->row[$x]->rowset->row[$y]->rank;
             $skills[$x]["skillPrimaryAtr"] = "".$xmlbalance->result->rowset->row[$x]->rowset->row[$y]->requiredAttributes->primaryAttribute;
             $skills[$x]["skillSecondAtr"] = "".$xmlbalance->result->rowset->row[$x]->rowset->row[$y]->requiredAttributes->secondaryAttribute;

             $o = 0;
             for ($z=0;$z<sizeOf($xmlbalance->result->rowset->row[$x]->rowset->row[$y]->rowset->row);$z++) {
                 if ($xmlbalance->result->rowset->row[$x]->rowset->row[$y]->rowset->attributes()->name == "requiredSkills") {
                     $skills[$x]["requiredSkills"]["".$xmlbalance->result->rowset->row[$x]->rowset->row[$y]->rowset->row[$z]->attributes()->typeID] = "".$xmlbalance->result->rowset->row[$x]->rowset->row[$y]->rowset->row[$z]->attributes()->skillLevel;
                     $o++;
                 }
             }

         }

    }
     echo '<pre>'; print_r($skills); echo '</pre>';

?>
```

If you go to the [original XML](http://pastebin.com/QiXtiZDe) ([link](http://pastebin.com/QiXtiZDe)), at line 452, you will see:

```
  <row groupName="Spaceship Command" groupID="257">
```

And that isn't show in [my array](http://pastebin.com/Rqt7vW8Q) ([link](http://pastebin.com/Rqt7vW8Q))...

That is one thing that i found that is missing...
I think that probally have more content that is missing too..

Why? How to fix it, please?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will only get a total of `sizeof($xmlbalance->result->rowset->row)` records. Because, in your 2nd `for` loop, you are basically storing your result in the same array element that is `$skills[$x]`.

Try this (I also higly encourage you to be as lazy as you can when you write code - by lazy I mean, avoid repeating / rewriting the same code over and over if possible) :

```
$filename = 'https://api.eveonline.com/eve/SkillTree.xml.aspx';
$xmlbalance = simplexml_load_file($filename);
$skills = array();    
foreach ($xmlbalance->result->rowset->row as $row)
{
    $groupName = $row->attributes()->groupName;
    $groupID = $row->attributes()->groupID;

    foreach ($row->rowset->row as $subRow) 
    {
        $skill['skillID'] = (string) $subRow->attributes()->typeID;
        $skill['skillName'] = (string) $subRow->attributes()->typeName;
        $skill['skillDesc'] = (string) $subRow->description;
        $skill['skillRank'] = (string) $subRow->rank;
        $skill['skillPrimaryAtr'] = (string) $subRow->requiredAttributes->primaryAttribute;
        $skill['skillSecondAtr'] = (string) $subRow->requiredAttributes->secondaryAttribute;

        foreach ($subRow->rowset as $subSubRowset) 
        {
            if ($subSubRowset->attributes()->name == 'requiredSkills') 
            {
                foreach ($subSubRowset->row as $requiredSkill) 
                {
                    $skill['requiredSkills'][(string) $requiredSkill->attributes()->typeID] = (string) $requiredSkill['skillLevel'];
                }
            }
        }

        $skills[] = $skill;
    }
}
print_r($skills);
```

Comment: The xml that i need to get is much complicated than those simple xml in question that u suggested.
The code is working, but that is missing some content... I need help to find why some content is missing.

Comment: Thank you for ur help ;) I tried, but the code isn't working too =( With this new code, i can't get the skill's Desc, skill's Rank and the required's skills list. Look: http://pastebin.com/CD2nSrG5 ... Ahhh this xml is so complicated and in my opnion very bad written :P

Comment: Ty very much!!! Its all woorking!! very nice! Thanks for simplifying the code  with the vars ;)